# Error in Socket binding with UDP protocol

Tags: c, sockets

I am newbie in socket programming using C. I found a tutorial that I was following, but I am getting an error in Socket binding when I run the server code. The print statement `printf("*** SERVER ERROR: Could not bind socket.\n");` gets triggered in the UDP server code below and I am not sure what the problem is.

**UDP SERVER CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 6000

int main() {

int serverSocket;

struct sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;

int status, addrSize, bytesReceived;

fd_set readfds, writefds;

char buffer[30];

char *response = "OK";

// Create the server socket serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (serverSocket < 0) {
    printf("*** SERVER ERROR: Could not open socket.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
// Setup the server address
memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr)); // zeros the struct
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serverAddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) SERVER_PORT);
// Bind the server socket
status = bind(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

if (status < 0) {
    printf("*** SERVER ERROR: Could not bind socket.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
// Wait for clients now
while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(serverSocket, &readfds);
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);
    FD_SET(serverSocket, &writefds); status = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, &writefds, NULL, NULL);
    if (status == 0) { // Timeout occurred, no client ready
    }
    else if (status < 0) {
        printf("*** SERVER ERROR: Could not select socket.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        addrSize = sizeof(clientAddr); bytesReceived = recvfrom(serverSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer),
        0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &addrSize);
        if (bytesReceived > 0) {
            buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
            printf("SERVER: Received client request: %s\n", buffer);
        }
        // Respond with an "OK" message
        printf("SERVER: Sending \"%s\" to client\n", response);
        sendto(serverSocket, response, strlen(response), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, addrSize);
        // If the client said to stop, then I'll stop myself
        if (strcmp(buffer, "stop") == 0)
        break;
    }
}
}
```

**UDP CLIENT CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define SERVER_PORT 6000
int main() {
int clientSocket, addrSize, bytesReceived;

struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
char inStr[80]; // stores user input from keyboard
char buffer[80]; // stores sent and received data
// Create socket 
clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (clientSocket < 0) {
    printf("*** CLIENT ERROR: Could open socket.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
// Setup address
memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVER_IP);
serverAddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) SERVER_PORT);
// Go into loop to commuincate with server now
while (1) {
    addrSize = sizeof(serverAddr);
    // Get a command from the user
    printf("CLIENT: Enter command to send to server ... ");
    scanf("%s", inStr);
    // Send command string to server
    strcpy(buffer, inStr);
    printf("CLIENT: Sending \"%s\" to server.\n", buffer);
    sendto(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, addrSize);
    // Get response from server, should be "OK" 
    bytesReceived = recvfrom(clientSocket, buffer, 80, 0,(struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, &addrSize);
    buffer[bytesReceived] = 0; // put a 0 at the end so we can display the string
    printf("CLIENT: Got back response \"%s\" from server.\n", buffer);
    
    if ((strcmp(inStr,"done") == 0) || (strcmp(inStr,"stop") == 0))
        break;
    }
    close(clientSocket); // Don't forget to close the socket !
    printf("CLIENT: Shutting down.\n");
}
```

Comment: Please use [perror](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to show the actual reason for the failure instead of just stating that it failed.

Comment: `// Create the server socket serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);` Code doesn't work if it is commented out. You haven't created the socket so of course you can't bind it.

Comment: Exactly, how you want to send the socket if you dont creat it! You has the verification but you have commentated the line that Will create the socket! You need to have this line `serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);` On the client side you have it!

Comment: thanks @kaylum. That was it, it works now.